# Appropriateness of Lagged Dependent Variable

Tags: regression, lags

I have a problem which seems to be quite common given the other questions I've seen related to this topic on StackExchange. But mine is a little more specific.

Assume that my model is of the following form

$Y_{t} = \alpha + \beta Y_{t-1} + \gamma X_t + \epsilon_t$

What tests/measures do I need to consider if I want to include the lagged dependent variable. E.g., are there any diagnostics/tests I need to run to ensure that the results are sensible.

Comment: As in linear regression, you would look at the p-values of the regression slope test. I'm not aware of ways to assess variable significance before fitting the model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Am I allowed to read off the p-values as if it was normal regression, or do I need to be wary of other things given the use of the DV.

Comment: Yep, it is the same standard procedure. However, [this article](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/) by Pr. Hyndman argues that variable selection through the use of p-values is generally bad practice (not just for time series) and proposes alternative methods.